# In Spring-XD Failed to access http endpoint http://localhost:9000

Tags: spring-xd

I use Spring-XD to create a stream,the stream can be deployed successfully,but when I post the message , it occurs "*Failed to access http endpoint http://localhost:9000"
I have tried to change the port of http,but there is the same wrong message

Comment: Please don't put code/config in comments; it's unreadable - edit the question instead. 9393 is the admin port and has nothing to do with the http source; take a look at the container log to make sure the http module is deployed correctly.

Comment: I can use the port 9393 to create and deploy a stream of "http | log" successfully,
and I can use the command of "http post" to send the message,
but I can't see the log of sending message  in the console of the container.
By the way,I can use the port of 9000 to create and deploy a stream of "http | log" successfully.
I can use the command of " http get http://localhost:9393" successfully ,
while to get info from 9000 prompt me "Fail to access http endpoint http://localhost9000".
By the way ,I in a distributed environment.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting the exception; it works fine for me. But GET on an HTTP source makes no sense; you need to POST data to the source.